# Can't use converter on list of tuples

Tags: c#, tuples, converters

First of all, my code references `System.ValueTuple`.

I have a list of tuples:

```
List<(string, string)> theme
```

and I would like to convert the first string of the tuple to a DateTime in one sweep, so I am trying to create a Converter to use with `List.ConvertAll`.
This doesn't give error:

```
var conv = new Converter<string,DateTime>(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x, "yyyy-MM-dd", null));
```

but clearly it's not what I need. When I try to simply use tuples as input/output for the lambda I get an error:

> (Delegate 'Converter)<(string,string),(DateTime,string)>' does not take two arguments)

```
var conv = new Converter<(string,string),(DateTime,string)>
           ( (x,y) => (DateTime.ParseExact(x, "yyyy-MM-dd", null),y) );
```

But I'm not passing two arguments. Or am I???
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work ?

```
var conv = new Converter<(string, string), (DateTime, string)>(x => (DateTime.ParseExact(x.Item1, "yyyy-MM-dd", null), x.Item2));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second attempt is very close. In the following statement, `(x,y)` implies that two arguments will be passed:

```
new Converter<(string,string),(DateTime,string)>((x,y) => (DateTime.ParseExact(x, "yyyy-MM-dd", null),y));
```

However the `Tuple` it will receive is a single argument, and as such the statement should be:

```
new Converter<(string,string),(DateTime,string)>(x => (DateTime.ParseExact(x.Item1, "yyyy-MM-dd", null),x.Item2));
```